# ¿Como soluciono este error de sintaxis de php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas al mezclar el html y el php, el error es unicamente de sintaxis y hace que los botones no se vean dentro de el ""  como realmente deberían verse, soy nuevo en php asi que disculpen el desastre. cualquier sugerencia sera agradecida

```
    <table>
        <thead>
          <caption>Agrupacion: Afro Latino</caption>
          <tr class="tituloTabla">
          <td>Nombre</td>
              <td>Apellido</td>
              <td>Cedula</td>
              <td>Direccion</td>
              <td>Telefono</td>
              <td class="columnaImagen"><img id="editarRegistro" src="../../img/editar.png"></td>
              <td class="columnaImagen"><img id="borrarRegistro" src="../../img/borrar.png"></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php

            $mRows="";
              while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $mRows.="<tr>
                            <td>$row[nombre]</td>
                            <td>$row[apellido]</td>
                            <td>$row[cedula]</td>
                            <td>$row[direccion]</td>
                            <td>$row[telefono]</td>
                            <td>"?><form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php"> <button type="submit"> Editar </button> </form><?php"</td>
                            <td> <form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php" ><button type="submit"> Borrar </button> </form> <?php "</td>
                        </tr>";     
                                   
              }

            echo $mRows;
            } 
        else {
           ?> <h3 id="errorTablas">Ningun usuario registrado</h3> <?php
        } 
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser que no estás concatenando strings correctamente cuando cierras y vuelves a abrir los tags de PHP. Eso se debe al desorden del código. Hay varias formas de arreglarlo, puede ser con solo php, o con html embebido con php, etc.
También recomiendo usar un buen IDE, acostumbrarse a indentar bien el código, etiqueta de cierre en la misma columna que la de apertura, 4 espacios por nivel. Hacerlo desde el principio ahorra muchos dolores de cabeza.

Una propuesta ordenada con PHP embebido sería:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        .
        . <!-- coloca el header de la tabla aquí -->
        .
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['apellido'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['cedula'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['direccion'];?></td>;
                <td><?php echo $row['telefono'];?></td>;
                <td>
                    <form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php">
                        <button type="submit"> Editar </button> 
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="GET" action="../../php/editarEstudiante.php" >
                        <button type="submit"> Borrar </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, seguire tus consejos, muy amable

Comment: amigo una cuestión mas, como logro que me pase los datos de ese usuario a otro archivo a traves del boton?

Comment: @DiegoGoncalves como los botones son formularios, puedes enviar el dato del id del estudiante en el action: `...editarEstudiante.php?esid=<?php echo $row['id_estudiante'];?>` O de otra forma, pones un *input hidden* con ese dato en el formulario del botón `<input type="hidden" name="esid" value="<?php echo $row['id_estudiante'];?>">`. En la página de la acción tendrás que hacer las consultas SQL para recuperar la información del usuario, si es necesario.

Comment: logre pasar los datos con el input hidden pero no se muy bien como tomarlos en el archivo del action, es decir, el dato llega y se ve en la url con el get pero no se como tomarlo a una variable, seguire intentando y cualquier cosa hare otro comentario, gracias amigo

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias por ayudarme, solo añadi $cedula = $_GET['cedula'];